# Z3 Java Bindings and CLI have Different Versions

Tags: java, z3, smt

I have downloaded the latest stable release of Z3 from GitHub, which is 4.8.7. With the CLI tool, when I write `$ ./z3 -version` I get `Z3 version 4.8.7 - 64 bit`, however when I do `System.out.println(Version.getFullVersion())` in my Java code after (which has `import com.microsoft.z3.*`), I get `Z3 4.8.6.0`.

Is there a way to upgrade the Z3 Java bindings to `4.8.7`, ie, the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

I followed my own instructions :-) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60403775/how-to-setup-a-java-development-environment-for-z3),  and with the resulting jar get:

```
System.out.println(Version.getFullVersion()) // Z3 4.8.7.0
```

Comment: By resulting jar you mean the one with Maven?

Comment: Yes although, it is just a copy of the one from the distribution zip

Comment: It looks like the version value comes from native call, perhaps you have more then one version of Z3 installed?