# How to setup a Java development environment for Z3

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation, z3

How to setup a Java development environment for the Z3 SMT solver?

**Note:** *Written and answered by the author, see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Z3 is a C++ application with Java bindings. Start by downloading the native distribution, Ubuntu in our case (similar approach should work for macOS), from   https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases ,  for example: `z3-4.8.7-x64-ubuntu-16.04.zip`.
- Unzip the build to a `Z3_DIR` . To simplify things, have the following exports:

```
 export Z3_DIR=<some_path>/z3-4.8.7-x64-ubuntu-16.04
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$Z3_DIR/bin
```

- Download the Java example that matches your Z3 version, compile and run it:

```sh
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Z3Prover/z3/z3-4.8.7/examples/java/JavaExample.java > JavaExample.java
$ javac -cp $Z3_DIR/bin/com.microsoft.z3.jar JavaExample.java
$ java -cp $Z3_DIR/bin/com.microsoft.z3.jar:. JavaExample
```

If all is well, you should see the example executing without errors.

- To use the Z3 jar with Maven, install it into the local maven repository:

```sh
$ mvn install:install-file \
   -Dfile=$Z3_DIR/bin/com.microsoft.z3.jar \
   -DgroupId=com.microsoft \
   -DartifactId=z3 \
   -Dversion=4.8.7 \
   -Dpackaging=jar \
   -DgeneratePom=true
```

A jar named `z3-4.8.7.jar` will be created in `<mavenrepo>/repository/com/microsoft/z3/4.8.7/`. It can be added to a maven project as dependency:

```xml
     <dependency>
         <groupId>com.microsoft</groupId>
         <artifactId>z3</artifactId>
         <version>4.8.7</version>
     </dependency>
```

- It is nice to have the Z3 API Java sources handy, these are available on Github: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/tree/z3-4.8.7/src/api/java . Note that the folder structure doesn't match the package name so you may want to copy the files to `com/microsoft/z3`  before registering them with an IDE.

**EDIT - macOS**
Unfortunately setting library path (`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`) on macOS doesn't work, for some details and a solution see here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/294

Answer (score 1):

[Z3-TurnKey](https://github.com/tudo-aqua/z3-turnkey) is a nice project which publishes a Maven artifact containing prebuilt native libraries for OS X, Windows and Linux which are linked at runtime.